# display date only once [elegant way] in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, hiveql

How do I display the date only once using the inbuilt [Date and Time functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-udf.html#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions)

In **mysql** we can do `select curdate();` to get

```
+------------+
| curdate()  |
+------------+
| 2013-07-23 |
+------------+
```

Trying `select unixtime();` in **Hive** gives me `FAILED: ParseException line 1:17 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting FROM near ')' in from clause`

Doing , `select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),"yyyy-MM-hh") from abc.xyz LIMIT 1;` gives me

```
OK
2013-07-03
```

my expected output but it doesn't seem really sensible to me to use a random database and its table just for accessing the `date`. What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Hive does not support constructing rows without reading any other tables (which is what you are trying to do when you run `select curdate()` or `select curdate() from dual`).

This is [work in progress](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1558).

Answer (score 1):

use `unix_timestamp()`
For other date functions look [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions)